# Want to store listview data locally once in a day

Tags: android, listview, caching, android-adapter, android-webservice

In my android app a list view contain so much data (Approx 1832 items) using webservices . I wanted to get the data from server once in a day and use that data without calling webservice . Is it possible to store that data in cache or somewhere else and represent it for whole day.

Comment: use sqlite db....

Comment: yes it is best!

Comment: Is there any other way instead of Sqlite.?

Comment: depends on data size, may sharedPreferences is one of option

Comment: You will get the data as text i think. Just save that text to file.

Comment: You coulde tell me which httpclient you are using, and enable its cache...so that api call would not be made the next time it fetches it :)

Comment: If you are getting the response in the JSON format , simply store the JSON response in SharedPreferences . Now when user navigates to the page then check if JSON data exists in the preferences , if exists parse that data and display in the list view . One thing to be noted to check day changes , store a date too in the shared preferences so that you can identify that day has changed , now you needs get data from server .

Answer (score 0):

SQ lite is the best solution for persistent data storage, for simplicity of usage you can use libraries such as db flow  [enter link description here](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow) , realm [enter link description here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java)

Also make use of job scheduler API (API level 21) or alarm manager for performing web service calls..

Comment: Using SQLite to store server response is not light weight task , It requires lot of code to store and to fetch data again from SQLite DB , Instead using SharedPreferences requires few lines of code to store and fetch data again .

Comment: But what if i have bundles of data to store .? Is that a proper way to store it on sharedPreference? @AndroidDev

Comment: In the question you are saying that you are getting data from web service , so your web service is returning data in the format of bundles ?

Comment: Nonsense. You receive text. And you extract strings from them which you put in the items of a listview. Or better yet  you put those strings in an array which you then offer to an adapter for your listview.

Comment: But what if i have bundles of data to store .? Here what do you mean by bundles ? From where you got these bundles ?